# Embed a specific checkbox matrix of taxonomy terms in a content type

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, webforms

I need design help for my website. I am trying to automate embedding a matrix (or webform) that lists taxonomy terms (url link) as rows and Categories as columns for each content in my custom content type. Matrix should be editable by the admin only. I want to use Views with contextual filter to view the matrix for each NID. A matrix will look something similar to below.

### Taxonomy        | Category-1 | Category-2 | Category-3

### Taxonomy-1      |   Checked  | Not Checked| Checked

### Taxonomy-2      | Not Checked| Checked    | Checked

Taxonomy-3      |   Checked  | Not Checked| Not Checked

I tried the following design options but I don't know which one will be best:

1- Term level module: I found this module great but I don't have the option to use checkboxes instead of radio button. I can load the Matrix with taxonomy term with one click. I opened a ticket with the module maintainer but no response yet.

2- Slickgrid module: I am not sure if I can get what I want with Slickgrid but I am having difficulty in using the module and display data

3- Tablefield module: I was not able to load taxonomy terms. I thought it is not a convenient tool.

4- Matrix field module: Module is not maintained anymore, as far as I know

5- Webforms: I thought of creating webforms and use them as Entity reference to each node ID. But I am not sure how I can use Views to show the SUBMITTED webforms for each nid.

Thanks for reading this. Your help, ideas and suggestions are really appreciated :)